# .NET core BCrypt password with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, bcrypt

I'm not entirely certain that the "core" part is necessary. I've not found anything on the combination of BCrypt and Entity Framework, so this may be something I fundamentally misunderstand or there may be a good reason not to do things this way.

I am creating a salt and using BCrypt to encrypt the password before storing (I think):

```
    public string Salt { get; set; }
    public string Password {
        get {
            return null;
        }
        set {
            Salt = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.GenerateSalt(12);
            BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.HashPassword(Salt + value);
        }
    }
```

Is this the right place/way to encrypt the password as it's being set? Where/how would I match against the Password record when logging in, the controller?

Comment: You're not storing the hashed password anywhere. You could refer to this page (it is not with Entity Framework but easy to integrate by yourself): [Use BCrypt to Hash Your Passwords: Example for C# and SQL Server](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/475262/UseplusBCryptplustoplusHashplusYourplusPasswords)

Comment: Just add a simple `return` in front of your last line of code (where you actualy crypt the password). You could also save yourself a line a code and call `BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.HashPassword(value,/*workFactor_here*/);`. Definition of the `HashPassword` function: 

*hash a password using the openbsd bcrypt scheme and salt generated by BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.GenerateSalt(int) using the given WorkFactor.*